# Is the reset button really required?

Tags: user-interface, usability

On a web ***contact form***, is the reset button really required? Is it really used by anyone? If I don't put it in a page, is there an usability fail?

10x!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Well, it's very useful to erase that textarea your customer just took the time to write, because they press the wrong button -before they lose it anyway because the session expires, and have to retype-

No, I really don't think it's useful.

Comment: +1: It's a pain in the @$$ for users with no recognizable benefit.

Comment: Best answer, hands down.

Comment: Check Cody Hatch's answer for a case where the button may make sense

Comment: +1; unfortunately my vote cant give more reputation!

Comment: Cody Hatch's answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402881/reset-button-is-really-required#402965

Comment: Experts: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000416.html   http://www.zefamedia.com/usability/to-submit-submit-or-submit/

Answer (score 30):

It's actually sometimes useful for web forms which will be accessed from public terminals - a good example would be a search form for a public library card catalogue.

Imagine if the search form has a lot of fields (author, year, keywords, topic, publisher, collection, title, series, whatever).  This lets you do very specific searches (all books by authors named John published in 1987), but once you've found the result you (or another user) may want to do a new search using a very different set of terms (all books about fish published by Random House.  A reset button can help a lot here, because you may otherwise find yourself manually clearing a large number of fields.

(Depending on implementation details, a reset button may also be useful if a user doesn't want the next user to see what they were searching for.  Again, this is useful in the context of a library, where privacy is a concern.)

Comment: This is actually a case where the button does make sense, +1

Comment: Okay, there's one place where you might want to do it.  Although It should be noted that the reset button should never be next to the submit button.  For any reason.  Ever.

Comment: You could also reload the form, couldn't you? Usually in those systems (i.e. the 3 or 4 I've used) simply getting the results and going back to a search would clear the form up.

Comment: This situation should be handled by going *forward* to a fresh form, not by providing a bomb waiting to blow up the user's precious input!

Comment: Redirect after Post preserves privacy.

Comment: This makes sense, but you left out the part about the form retaining previous values because that, too, might be useful.  As others have noted, the regular practice is to always load a fresh form.  There are valid reasons for not doing that, and that's the unspoken part of this answer.

Comment: So in a nutshell, if your users can benefit from the form retaining the values from previous iterations, then a reset feature /might/ be appropriate.  The devil is in the UI.  It needs to be as obvious as a link to a fresh form.  They're functionally identical.

Comment: Yes, the best UI, I guess, would be if the page kept your terms after a search, but offered a link/button to a fresh search. The reset button here would have the advantage of not requiring a round-trip to the server.

Comment: I guess in this case if the developer didn't set autocomplete = false you can forget about the privacy.  I think he's right, for public settings there may be a use, but I would think most users would close the browser (since most kiosks allow this and just open a new window).  If the remembering of the fields was set to false then their info would be cleared.

Comment: I meant to add you can maybe do a new session per browser window so that in that case the back uses the session info to repopulate the fields temporarily for that same user, but not permanently (after he closes the browser).

Answer (score 4):

I honestly don't think so in the general case, but you should talk to your users or otherwise examine how they use your system to make sure.

General rule of thumb: If you aren't sure that it's a requirement and you have no way of knowing, don't include it.  You can always include it on a later iteration.

Answer (score 4):

The reset button must be the safe winner in any contest measuring a uses/usefulness ratio since it's omnipresent and fully useless.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a) completely useless to 99% of users; and b) requires far too much work in a typical LOB application. Often business analysts add requirements for the Reset button without giving any thought as to **why** this feature is required.

Answer (score 3):

add it to the webform and log it whenever a user clicks it. that will provide information for your specific page if it's needed or not. we cannot guess if people want it or not.
just use simple analyzing tools of users need it or not.

Comment: One of the best answers on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary in most web-pages. If you're entering information, and you enter it wrong, then you'll need to go through every wrong text-box and re-enter it. The reset button is, at minimum, one extra button click on top of that.

If you don't want to enter information, you just don't click the submit button.

The only time I see a reset button being useful is if you have a multi-page workflow, and need to be able to start from scratch. Even then I would suggest re-designing the workflow.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the reset button is completely useless on the majority of forms. I mean think about it... Can you ever imagine a time were you would want to complete remove **all** of the information you typed in? Not likely. Most users tend to make edits to specific fields not the entire form.

In the case that you have to have such a secondary action like a reset button it's better that that button is a little smaller as well as colored a little differently. Let the user know "this button is different" and apply Fitt's Law to make it a little harder to click on.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely NOT required. In fact, it's a bad idea to use it if you have a long form and have a RESET button at the bottom because you could make some people really angry if they find out that they accidently hit "RESET" and their data is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Required. Make sure you swap the position of the reset and submit buttons on some of your forms. Better yet, write code to randomly swap their position once in a blue moon.

In all seriousness, I've never used one. When I removed it from the forms on my school's registrar's site that I was working on when I was a student, nobody said anything. So I say leave it off.

Comment: +1 for your first paragraph making me LOL :-)

Comment: Adrian, it was a joke. Read the second paragraph. The answer is that you don't need a reset button.

Answer (score 1):

Not only on the contact form. I can't also find the benefit of reset button in any type of HTML form, IMHO. But I tend to put it every time I create a form :)

Answer (score 1):

Only reason I could think of is on a preview & confirm scenario, where a user might modify part of their entry before hitting the big bad send button, and actually decide itt made more sense the first time around

Answer (score 1):

I usually leave out the reset button, because I've never seen anybody use it.

I often use the free space for a cancel button which returns the user to where he came from in the first place (the page linking to the form). Makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

What if I says it **IS** useful? But not in every form.

I use it with the "UPDATE" part in a CRUD application sometimes.

Say SO for example, I hit an *edit* link on a question.... and made some edits and reread it... but then I decided it is not a good edit... I have to reload the page or go back to the last page and hit the edit link again to get the original text.

Whereas, if there is a reset button slapped there, it'd be easy.

And there is always CTRL+Z.. so why not?

There are some good uses but just don't slap it in silly like what most ancient HTML books would teach you to.

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful for clearing radio buttons without using Javascript.

In the form below either zero or one radio button may be selected:

```
        Select any one option for any Item(s):     
        Option 'A'    Option 'B'    Option 'C'
Item 1     o              o            o 
Item 2     o              o            o     
Item 3     o              o            o 
Item 4     o              o            o
```

If a user changes his mind or accidentally clicks on an item's button he didn't want, a reset button will clear the whole form, which seems to be only way to get rid of the selection without using Javascript.

Comment: Add "no answer" radio button. HTML4 specification discourages use of unselected radios.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how large the form is and how big the chance that you actually want to do this. TBH, i've been developing websites for years and never really added one to forms.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful on a form that repeats your previous information. I have had cases in admin interfaces where the users want what they typed in last time, so they don't have to remember. However, on those occasions when they want the form to reset, they simply press the "clear" (or reset) button.

On a one-time form a reset button would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

A reset button should be used only when there is default information.  An example is [this form](http://kalsey.com/tools/buttonmaker/).  What if I make changes to most of the values but then would like to get it back to it's original state?  I guess I could reload the page as long as it doesn't resend my POST.  Or I could just hit a simple reset button.  The button was never intended to clear all information entered by the user but to reset preset data.

Comment: Browsers these days have Undo function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the usability fail will present itself if and when a user or business owner complains about the absence.

Definitely not required as a "standard" feature and usually a very bad idea with the exception of the special cases given above where the functionality seems to add value. However the most of the cases offered as examples above could be dealt with in different (and I would suggest, better) ways than with the, often awful, reset button.

Answer (score 0):

### Reset is for use with HTTP status 204 only

Destination of the form can send `204 No Content` response, which causes browsers to leave the current page unchanged.

In that situation reset button is most reliable way to reset form to original state (page reload could re-send the form).

However I can't come up with realistic use-case for it anyway.